# How to Access `NSArray` elements

Tags: ios6, nsarray

I have a array like this

`

```
 (lldb) po list
 (NSArray *) $1 = 0x0759f120 <__NSArrayI 0x759f120>(
 {
EmployeeCode = 7593;
InDate = "27/02/2013";
InTime = "08:11";
InTime2 = "00:00";
OutDate = "27/02/2013";
OutDate2 = "01/01/1901";
OutTime = "17:42";
OutTime2 = "00:00";
Present = 1;
}
)
```

`

How can I access each an individual elements in here. Plz help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `NSArray` contains values in `NSDictionary` format, so at each `index` within array you'll get a `NSDictionary`, so you can access it like this,

```
NSLog(@"Employee Code = %@", [[yourArray objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"EmployeeCode"]);
```

**where, index = 0 & index < [yourArray count]**